# sqlalchemy, postgresql and relationship stuck in "idle in transaction"

Tags: python, session, transactions, sqlalchemy

I have a problem related to sqlalchemy and postgresql.

```
class Profile(Base):
  ...

  roles = relationship('Role', secondary=role_profiles,
                       backref='profiles', lazy='dynamic')
```

When running (`current_user` is an instance of the `Profile` class):

```
roles = current_user.roles.filter().all()
```

using sqlalchemy I get `idle in transaction` for all the selects for reading the profile in postgresql.

**Edit:**

From echoing the query I see that every select starts with:

```
BEGIN (implicit)
```

**Another edit:**

After adding

```
pool_size=20, max_overflow=0
```

to the `create_engine` it seems like the `idle in transaction`-statements are being rolled back when the number of idle are getting to big. Any idea on this and would this be a bad solution to the problem?

How do I manage this and how would I go about getting rid of the `BEGIN` for selects?

Comment: did you try `pool_timeout=90` for example ? i found it [here in the doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/engines.html?highlight=pool_timeout)

Comment: I don't think that really fixes the problem. I'd like to get rid of begin on selects or automatically commit on selects.

Comment: You are not properly ending transactions. You must either `commit` or `rollback` your transactions. The `begin` part is implicit (as you noted), but it needs to be ended correctly. Also: Why do you have an empty filter statement? Does that make sense? Are you in a web context or a different one? Finally, though highly unrecommended, you could use `autocommit` mode (but really, don't).

Comment: @javex, thanks. I've been reading as much and got most out of transactions but there are still some from my `relationsships` that I can't really touch. Is sqlalchemy automatically closing those?.

Comment: Normally you should operate on a single session. Still, I don't get what you are trying to achieve when doing `current_user.roles.filter().all()`. Why not just do `current_user.roles`? That gives a list and executes automatically in the context of the session of which `current_user` is part of (e.g. if you queried like this: `session.query(User).filter(User.id == some_id).one()` then this will all be handled automatically.

Comment: actually if you look at the relationship you see that it is `lazy='dynamic'` which means that it's not queried yet but a query to query.

Comment: @javex, most of the issues were related to what you wrote and i've cleaned that up. i also read up more on the relationships so that's only a `current_user.roles` now. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Starting with SQLAlchemy 0.8.2 you can disable the implicit `BEGIN` statements when calling `create_engine()`

```
engine = create_engine(uri, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
```

There are some subtle implications to this change. First, there statements that were not quietly hid in unterminated transaction will be quietly ignored

```
session.execute("DELETE FROM department WHERE department_id=18")
sys.exit(0)
```

*default*:

```
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: show standard_conforming_strings
LOG:  statement: DELETE FROM department WHERE department_id=18
LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
```

*autocommit*:

```
LOG:  statement: show standard_conforming_strings
LOG:  statement: DELETE FROM department WHERE department_id=18
```

Second, updating multiple updates are no longer automic, and `rollback()` is only conditionally effective:

```
department = Department(u"HR")
session.add(department)
session.flush()
employee = Employee(department.department_id, u'Bob')
session.add(employee)
session.rollback()
```

*default*:

```
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO department (name) VALUES ('HR') RETURNING department.department_id
LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
```

*autocommit*:

```
LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO department (name) VALUES ('HR') RETURNING department.department_id
```

Setting SQLAlchemy's `isolation_level` on the Engine object is effective for
many applications. It unfortunate that `Session.begin()` does not always mean `BEGIN TRANSACTION;`

Answer (score 3):

SQLA by default always operates in a transaction (some info [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#unitofwork-transaction)). In a web context most frameworks would handle committing this transaction for you at the end of the request (e.g. [pyramid_tm](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tm/en/latest/)). If you're not using a framework, or this is another type of application, you'll want to commit or rollback when you're finished, or at an appropriate point.

It may be possible to configure SQLA such that it doesn't automatically start a transaction but as far as I can see it's not how it is intended to be used so you'll probably have better luck not trying to fight it :).