# SQLAlchemy idle in transaction

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have application writen Python 3.6, Flask and SQLAlchemy (PostgreSQL).

I encountered problems with  hanging `idle in transaction` connections in my db. It's probably because I don't commit nor rollback after select queries.

I use default SQLALchemy configuration: `db = SQLAlchemy()`

Sample endpoint that creates hanging connections:

```
class Test(Resource):

    def get(self, pk):
        return User.query.get(pk).serialize()
```

What's the way of handling such select queries? Should I select then commit? Or select then rollback? or entirely close connection after request? But closing connection causes that on every request there will be new connection to database opened.

What's best way?

Comment: Don't close the connection. Just the `Session` at the end of a request etc. (in case of thread-local scoped session, remove). See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/#declarative for pointers, though to my understanding Flask-SQLAlchemy should handle that out of the box.

Comment: A session is removed only on app teardown. What should I do after request? Rollback? Close session? Which approach is better? Also If I close a session, what will happen with not committed/rollbacked transactions?

Comment: There's a lengthy writeup about the subject in the documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it. When you throw [scoped sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html) in the mix you'll want to `remove()` the registered `Session` object in a suitable point. The removed session will be closed for you, which ends ongoing transactions, frees resources etc.

Comment: To my reading the Flask docs would hint that `@app.teardown_appcontext` handlers will be fired after requests as well.

Answer (score 7):

This article describes what's happening and how to deal with it: http://oddbird.net/2014/06/14/sqlalchemy-postgres-autocommit/

Short answer: SQLAlchemy defaults to implicitly opening a new transactions. You could either commit after every SELECT or turn on autocommit (read the article to learn more).

Here's an SO post on the matter.
[sqlalchemy, postgresql and relationship stuck in "idle in transaction"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438300/sqlalchemy-postgresql-and-relationship-stuck-in-idle-in-transaction)

Comment: So it is possible to disable autocommit mode, but it's hacky and risky? Also, SQLAlchemy docs say that autocommit mode is legacy. Does this mean that using autocommit mode may be dangerous? According to SO `It unfortunate that Session.begin() does not always mean BEGIN TRANSACTION;`

Comment: Autocommit is rarely a good solution. It'd be much better to identify where the sessions / connections should be committed / rolled back / closed. Usually a session's lifetime is tied to a request's etc.

Comment: So I would like to do it in my `BaseEndpoint` class, after dispatch_request. I think a better solution is to rollback here instead of commit? So I keep only transactions that were committed explicitly during a request, all the others will be rollbacked. What do you think?